# How to base64 encode a raw PDF content (bytes) in JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, base64, byte, encode, binaryfiles

I need to base64 encode the content of a raw PDF (already got the raw content).
but i don't know why, but btoa() expect the input to be an ASCII char composed string.

```
btoa('﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿ééééééé');
>> InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
```

Is there any way to convert raw bytes to base64 in javascript without recoding the base64 algo ? (by the way, working for images, and whatever file content)

By advance, Thanks for your answers !

[[image]

Comment: "already got the raw content" - care to show how exactly?

Comment: I don't want to display the content, i want to base64 encode it, in order to send the encoded content on severals microservices

Comment: Georg wants to know how you read/load the raw content? This is why the complete code snippet will be very useful. Or, at least, tell us how you store bytes (for example, as `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob`)?

Comment: I store (uncasted input) the content in utf8 string buffer. I also tried in a blob, unsuccessfully.
Here is a part of my input : ��D��A�-�z�� A�D<-�z��eB�B�E �

```

import base64
print(base64.b64encode("��D��A�-�z�� A�D<-�z��eB�B�E �"))
# result should be 77+977+9RO+/ve+/vUHvv70t77+9eu+/ve+/vSBB77+9RDwt77+9eu+/ve+/vWVC77+9Qu+/vUUg77+9```
(modifié)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing contents as `Blob`, use the `FileReader` object to convert it to data URI, then remove its prefix:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
  var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');
  console.log(b64);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(your_blob);
```

Another way, if you are storing it as `ArrayBuffer`:

```
// Create a Uint8Array from ArrayBuffer
var codes = new Uint8Array(your_buffer);

// Get binary string from UTF-16 code units
var bin = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, codes);

// Convert binary to Base64
var b64 = btoa(bin);
console.log(b64);
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer

Comment: Do you have any example of storing a PDF into a Blob using a remote URL as the source PDF? Not locally neither using select files in HTML.